# Repeating exception handling

Tags: c#, web-services, exception

I have a question about repeating exception handling...

For example: Webmethods have try-catch block and inside try block there is execution code. This try-catch blocks are the same for each webmethod.

Is there any possibility to make it easier, more maintainable, without repeating the same code? 
I know about aspects, but is there any other solution?

The code lang is C#, but I thing in general solution.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: A *general solution* for exception handling usually is a very bad idea. If you require the exact same `try/catch` block for each and every `WebMethod` then I tend to think there's something wrong with your design at a larger scale. Would you mind giving just one example of an handling you would like to repeat?

Answer (score 1):

Using functional programming principles, you can pass the action or method that you want to be executed in a certain way.

In C# you can make a method like this to standardize your code:

```
public void HandleExceptions(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch (ExceptionA exa)
    {

    }
    catch (ExceptionB exb)
    {

    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
HandleExceptions(() =>
{
    //insert code to be handled by try/catch structure
    Method1();
});
HandleExceptions(() =>
{
    Method2();
});
```